# Difference between Drag force and virtual force

Tags: forces, fluid-dynamics, drag

When an object submerged in a flowing fluid, it will experience a drag force due to shear stress and pressure. Now, I read that there is something called "virtual force" as well acting on the body. I don't quite understand where this force comes from or exactly what it is. And is it connected to the drag force somehow?

Comment: Where did you read this

Comment: I stumbled upon the added mass concept while searching online regarding forces on bodies in fluid. There's a Wikipedia page on it for example. I couldn't quite understand how the added mass concept was related to/if it was related to drag force. To me, it wasn't so intuitive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

F.W. Bessel introduced the concept of 'added mass' or 'virtual mass' when he observed that the period of a pendulum moving in a fluid differs from that in a vacuum.

Consider an object of mass $m$ connected to a spring of spring constant $k$ moving inside a fluid of viscosity $\mu$. The equation of motion is given by:

$$m\dfrac{d^2x}{dx^2}+\mu\dfrac{dx}{dt}+kx=0$$

The natural frequency is given by:
$$\omega=\sqrt{\dfrac{k}{m}}$$

Note that the drag does not change the natural frequency. So experimentally, if the natural frequency pendulum is different in a fluid compared to a vacuum, the effective mass has to be different.

$$\omega=\sqrt{\dfrac{k}{m+m_a}}$$

Here $m_a$ is the added mass. Intuitively, one can think of this as some fluid that gets carried with your pendulum bob as it oscillates. The corresponding extra force you need to supply to account for this extra mass is called virtual force.

$$(m+m_a)\dfrac{d^2x}{dx^2}+\mu\dfrac{dx}{dt}+kx=0$$

This is a reasonable thought, since if there was no such thing, you would have infinite sheer at the boundary.

[image]

**Difference between drag and added mass**

Suppose you want to slow down the rotation of a merry-go-round. Drag is like standing outside and rubbing your hands against the wheel to slow it down. Virtual mass is like jumping onto the platform, increasing the effective moment of inertia to slow it down. Though both are slowing it down, one affects the motion externally while the other changes the intrinsic properties.

[Reference 1](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/2-016-hydrodynamics-13-012-fall-2005/6124a1fd14e811d9ea753f85e0dfc8d0_2005reading6.pdf)

[Reference 2](http://brennen.caltech.edu/fluidbook/basicfluiddynamics/unsteadyflows/addedmass/introduction.pdf)